# Any idea why this .htaccess can cause 500 internal server error?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ api/index.php [QSA,L]
```

I took up Slim microframework's sample .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

and added `api` before index.php and now my app doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have index.php inside api folder, try changing it to

`RewriteRule ^ api\/index.php [QSA,L]`